# Making a cell change color based on the value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I want to have cell A29:A35 change colors based on the text within cell A3:A15

For example, cell A29 would change green If found within the range of A3:A15.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Create a conditional formatting rule for range `A29:A35` using the "Custom formula is" option and enter the following formula:

```
=MATCH(A29,$A$3:$A$15,0)
```

### Explanation

The `=MATCH` formula will look through a range and return the position of a search result (in this case `A29`) within the range (in this case, `$A$3:$A$15`). If the value is not found, it will return an error. The final argument of `0` specifies to only look for exact matches.

Conditional formatting will interpret any non-zero number as a successful result and apply the formatting change, which is to color a cell green by default. If the value is not found and an error is returned, the rule is not applied.

Functions used:

- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)